# rosmake rgbdslam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg,my cpu use rate achives 100%,which causes my computer crashed, and the make dosent complete.I use ubuntu 64 and my computer is 4G memory.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163751/rosmake-rgbdslam/) by [360693047](https://answers.ros.org/users/15171/360693047/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vdonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/14946/vdonkey/) on 2014-05-11**:
no idea. but maybe you can try catkin_make. copy rgbdslam_freiburg to your catkin home's src sub dir. run catkin_make at catkin home dir

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-05-11**:
Do you run out of memory? Are you overheating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check if you have parallel compilation enabled, e.g. in the environment variable $ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS (also there will be multiple compiler processes in "top" when you run rosmake).

4GB might not be enough if you do compile in parallel, as some very memory hungry template libraries are used.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0